# Dependencies from maven external jar not getting resolved in intellij

Tags: transitive-dependency, maven-dependency

I have created a jar for my java project A. I am using it in another project B. But dependencies from A's pom.xml are not getting resolved in project B.

I deployed project A's jar in project B using dependency. jar has been added in maven external jar successfully in B in intellij. Also built the project B successfully. Still getting error class not found for classes being accessed from A.  What could be reason?